# My app crashes in IllegalStateExtension in android

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

Help me - how to solve this issue?

Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

My Java code:after extending AppCompactActivity in the place ActionbarActivity I am getting same error

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

 Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Home","Events"};
    int Numboftabs =2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);



}
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

     <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<com.chn.shruthi.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: plz post your code xml and java...........!!

Comment: Please post your Manifest.xml.

Comment: Better add your styles.xml. Something is wrong there

Comment: I am already posted my style.xm under java file

Comment: Don't extend `ActionBarActivity` it's deprecated .practice to extend `AppCompactActivity`..

Comment: am am change my code by replacing AppCompactActivity again am am getting same problem@Anoop M

Comment: Have you replaced your theme in the right way as Aawaz Gyawali mentioned.?

Comment: You have only a single `values` folder right ? or any folder like `values-v21/values-v22` ?

Comment: Post your tool_bar layout also..

Comment: no values v7/valuesv14@Anoop

Comment: Replace themes in every style.xml as well..

Comment: thaq u sooooo much @Anoop I resolved my isssue my following your steps

Comment: Your welcome.Go ahead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you done well but still getting same error ?

Now u just replace your toolbar code like below..Add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` for parent ViewGroup.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#ff80"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Use the theme in all `style.xml` as well.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red_primary_color_dark</item>
 </style>
```

And let me know if any further error.

Answer (score 0):

Dont's extend ActionBarActivity and don't set your activity's theme's windowActionBar to be false,it will confict with ActionBarActivity's setting.

Comment: where i need to change my code please tell me I am new to android,I am extends with AppcompactActivity after chaging it i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines in styles.xml:-

`<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

**OR**

Simply make your styles.xml like this:-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

You don't need two seperate xml file for lolipop and pre-lolipop. If you have created it, just delete the v2* styles file and use Compile SDK Version to 23.
Hope you get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: after remove that i am getting same error@awaz gyawali